# Constraint error when updating m2m relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a M2M relationship with a junction table, set up in the models as:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_alert', 'alert_id', 'user_id');
}

public function alerts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Alert::class, 'user_alert', 'user_id', 'alert_id');
}
```

When editing an alert with this line, I get the following error.

```
Alert::findOrFail($request->id)->users()->syncWithoutDetaching($users);
```

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`homestead`.`user_alert`, CONSTRAINT `user_alert_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `user_alert` (`alert_id`, `id`, `user_id`) values (43, 1, 0))
```

The user_id argument 0 is causing the error and I have no idea where it's coming from. Doing a `dd($users)` shows something similar to:

```
array:5 [
    0 => array:1 [
        "id" => 1
    ]
    1 => array:1 [
        "id" => 1
    ]
    2 => array:1 [
        "id" => 2
    ]
]
```

The 0 first appears in a call to `/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.php`

```
    "file" => "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.php"
    "line" => 254
    "function" => "insert"
    "class" => "Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder"
    "type" => "->"
    "args" => array:1 [▼
      0 => & array:1 [▼
        0 => array:3 [▼
          "alert_id" => 43
          "id" => 1
          "user_id" => 0
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Frustratingly, the M2M relationship works when creating a new alert.

I hope it's not too relevant, but this is Laravel 7.

Hope somebody has some advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the format of the $users data. `syncWithoutDetaching` can  take **collection of User models** or **array of user ids**. Format you provided is not supported because takes array keys (0,1,2 in your example) as user ids.

So please provide `syncWithoutDetaching` with collection of User models or array of user ids.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, unfortunately this gives the error:
```Trying to get property 'id' of non-object/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/DelegatesToResource.php#136```

Comment: Actually I solved it with your solution by changing the line:
```Alert::findOrFail($request->id)->users()->syncWithoutDetaching($users);```
to:

```$alert = Alert::findOrFail($request->id);```
```$alert->users()->syncWithoutDetaching($users);```

Thanks!